# How do I sync purchased apps from the Zune client to my phone?

Tags: windows-phone, zune-software

I have just finished setting up a Samsung Omnia 7 with the Zune client on Windows 7. The phone works great, and I can sync music, videos and pictures from my PC to the phone using the Zune client.

I have also 'purchased' two free apps using the marketplace in the Zune client: Youtube and 1Password. Both apps now show up in the marketplace as "already purchased."

But they have not (yet) appeared on the phone. I have synced and resynced several times, but the apps are just not appearing on the phone.

One thing that might be related: when I visit marketplace on the phone, I can't access it because "Marketplace is not yet available in your country/region."

How can I get apps onto the phone?

-- 
Edit

I have changed my Live ID account region to United States, reset the phone, chose Eastern Time for the time zone, singed in with my Live ID, connected to my PC and the market place is still not available. I also turned off location services, doesn't help.

--
Edit 2

I have created a new Live ID using my web browser and set my location settings to United States, New York, ZIP 12345. I reset the phone, signed in with the new Live ID and now when I try to access the marketplace I get this message:

> There is a problem completing your request. Try again later. Error
>   code: c00cee47

Answer (score 0):

You can only register ONE Live ID with any phone. Otherwise one phone could share data from several people. In this case you need to set your device to your correct registered live-ID you've used first time. Hardware-Reset of WP7 is not needed.

Please check what phones are registered with Zune.
[image: Zune WP7 registered]

You can check your device link if you're an developer here:

https://users.create.msdn.com/account/profile
[image: Zune registered devices]

And last but not least is to setup your XBox Account and credit card information with valid values:

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/howto/wp7/apps/set-up-an-xbox-live-account.aspx